# Flutter: Different routes for appbar and phone back buttons

Tags: flutter, widget

How to have different routes for appbar and phone back buttons?

For the appbar back button, it will route to the previous screen.
For the phone back button, it will close and exit the app.

Currently, in the code below, both close and exit the app

```
class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => exitApp(context),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('If appbar arrow pressed, go Back Previous Page'),
          //automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        ),
        body: Container()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

From exitApp.dart

```
Future<bool> exitApp(BuildContext context) async {
  return (await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
      title: new Text('Are you sure?'),
      content: new Text('Do you want to exit an App'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
          child: new Text('No'),
        ),
        new FlatButton(
          onPressed:  () => SystemNavigator.pop(), // () => exit(0), //() => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
          child: new Text('Yes'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )) ??
      false;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide your `AppBar` the `leading` property and assign it e.g. to an `IconButton`:

```
AppBar(
    leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: routeToPreviousScreen(),
    )
)
```

And to the `WillPopScope` widget provide your exit funciton:

```
WillPopScope(onWillPop: () async => exitApp(context),)
```

Now you assigned the `AppBar` back button and the phone back button two different functions.